# getting a curious NullPointerException when i want to switch from an Activity to a MapActivity

Tags: android, mapactivity

i gain a NullPointerException when i try to switch to a MapActivity.

I´m getting it at the **super.oncreate(savedInstanceState);** call, which has to be the first line in the **public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** method. In the debugger i can see, that savedInstanceState is indeed null.

this is the code i use to switch to that activity, it gets called when a Button gets clicked. With another, normal Activity it works just fine. Its from inside the start Activity and the Method gets called from an **OnTouchListener**.

```
public void buttonLiveTouch(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LiveActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The documentation to the normal Activity says

> If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null.

so i guess its intended that its null, since MapActivity is "just" an extension of the normal Activity. 
so uehm, what am i overseeing, what is wrong?

ErrorLog from LogCat:

```
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{m.p/m.p.LiveActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:601)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:165)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore.writeBlockX(AndroidPersistentStore.java:140)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore.writeBlock(AndroidPersistentStore.java:169)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.PreferenceStore.ensurePreferencesLoaded(PreferenceStore.java:178)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.PreferenceStore.readPreference(PreferenceStore.java:86)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.BasePersistentStore.readPreference(BasePersistentStore.java:41)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.StaticUtil.readPreferenceAsDataInput(StaticUtil.java:271)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.loadOrRequestCookie(DataRequestDispatcher.java:493)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.<init>(DataRequestDispatcher.java:390)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.createInstance(DataRequestDispatcher.java:341)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap(MapActivity.java:548)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:422)
**03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):   at m.p.LiveActivity.onCreate(LiveActivity.java:20)**
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
03-28 09:09:54.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     ... 11 more
```

and just in case, the code of the class till the point where the NullPointerException gets thrown

```
package m.p;


import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import m.p.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class LiveActivity extends MapActivity  {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //line 19
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //line 20
        setContentView(R.layout.live); //line 21
```

and my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="m.p"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_hg_03"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SteuerungActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LiveActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DataActivity" />
    </application>
```

---

dear future reader:
i haven´t found out what the reason for this error is, but this is how i "solved" this issue:
1)i deleted the avd
2)i reinstalled the sdk version
3)i created a new avd

Comment: I have never seen this error before. Your code seems fine from what I can see. What are you testing this on?

Comment: im testing this by the emulator (3.2 Google Api)

Comment: it seems im not the first one whos having this error... on
http://www.androidside.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=B49&wr_id=62163
someone else seems to have that problem... but as far as i can understand what the google Translation gives me, it is unsolved....

Comment: If you can create a sample project that demonstrates this error, post the source to it somewhere -- I would be interested in taking a look at it.

Comment: @CommonsWave http://dl.dropbox.com/u/377944/sampleA.7z

Comment: Your app runs perfectly fine for me.

Comment: .... on my privat pc im not having that error too...... >.<
guess ill just reinstall eclipse +sdk tomorrow.... and hope for the best.

Comment: @CommonsWave thank you for looking into the project. Without that it would have taken quite a while till i would have reinstalled it... it was enough to renew the avd and the sdk version

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the documentation of the `MapActivity`:

> Here we initialize static factories, create the map object and the
>   traffic service, but do not begin any threads. The subclass should
>   create (or inflate) its MapView object after calling through to
>   super.onCreate().

This means that Map activity also does some logic on the bundle. It obviously fails in certain state. I am not entirely convinced it has something to do with the bundle being passed in. I wish I could see the code of `android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore` or something else in the stacktrace.